# show animation and hide other when page is loading

Tags: jquery

I don't want to show my page until its loads.
and also want to show an animation

I am using this code

```
jQuery(window).load(function (){
jQuery('#loading').show();
jQuery('#main-container').hide();

});
```

but its like something is incorrect.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd like that the other way around, hiding the loader and showing the container when the page loads? Seems a bit strange to show a loading message and hide the page when it's finally loaded? On the other hand, using window.load and this sort of thing is usually not great for UX.

Comment: You should show the loader at the very beginning, in <head> you can place its html into body, and show it, and only after that you write: $(document).ready(function() { // hide loader, show content });

Comment: This code has a syntax error. jQuery(window).load{ that nipple bracket should be a parenthesis. Make sure to open the console and look for errors before posting a SO question

Comment: `jQuery(window).load{` this is editing  mistake. anyway thanks, updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should hide your page and show the loader initially with CSS

```css
#main-container { display: none }
#loading { display: block }
```

And after the page has been loaded then you hide the loader and show the content

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#loading').hide();
    jQuery('#main-container').show();
});
```

Comment: would make more sense to have the loader show by default in css, rather than wait for `ready` event to fire

Comment: @charlietfl makes perfect sense - updated the answer.. thanks